# sqLite Record Not Moving previous

Tags: android, sqlite

When I click on next button it goes to next record. But when I click on previous button it won't move the record.

Java File

```
package com.example.akshay.eventmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 7/13/2015.
 */
public class open extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    int year, month, day;
   public DataBaseHelper myDB;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
    Date myDate;
  public Cursor cursor;
    Cursor forPrevious;


    String ID, TITLE, VENUE, DISPLAYDATE, DATE, TIME, DATEFROMDB, MONTHFROMDB, YEARFROMDB, GotDate, MINUTES, HOURS, ADDR;
    String[] TIMEPARTS, split;

    Button Next, Previous;
    TextView tVenue, tVTime, tVDate, tVAddress;

    String IDToPass;
   public int IDD = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.open);
        getCurrentDate();
        Casting();

        myDB = new DataBaseHelper(this);


       /* Toast.makeText(this, VENUE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, DATE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, TIME, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, ADDR, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/


    }

    public void getCurrentDate() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH); // Note: zero based!
        day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    }

    public void Casting() {
        Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNext);
        Previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPrevious);

        tVTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        tVenue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvVenue);
        tVAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
        tVDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        Next.setOnClickListener(this);
        Previous.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bNext:


                cursor = myDB.getDataById(IDD);
                IDToPass = String.valueOf(IDD);
                if (cursor.moveToNext()) {


                    VENUE = cursor.getString(3);
                    DATE = cursor.getString(7);
                    TIME = cursor.getString(8);
                    ADDR = cursor.getString(6);
                    IDD++;
                    Toast.makeText(this, IDToPass , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    tVTime.setText(TIME);
                    tVDate.setText(DATE);
                    tVenue.setText(VENUE);
                    tVAddress.setText(ADDR);
                }

                break;

            case R.id.bPrevious:


                cursor = myDB.getDataById(IDD);



                if (cursor.moveToPrevious()) {
                    IDD = IDD - 1;
                    Toast.makeText(this, IDToPass , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    VENUE = cursor.getString(3);
                    DATE = cursor.getString(7);
                    TIME = cursor.getString(8);
                    ADDR = cursor.getString(6);

                    tVTime.setText(TIME);
                    tVDate.setText(DATE);
                    tVenue.setText(VENUE);
                    tVAddress.setText(ADDR);
                }

                break;
        }


    }
}
```

DataBaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.akshay.eventmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 7/12/2015.
 */
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static final String DB_NAME = "MyEventManagerFinal.db";
    static final String TABLE_NAME = "MyEvents";

    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Title";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Description";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Venue";
    public static final String COL_5 = "Latitude";
    public static final String COL_6 = "Longitude";
    public static final String COL_7 = "Address";
    public static final String COL_8 = "Date";
    public static final String COL_9 = "Time";
    SQLiteDatabase myDB;
    Cursor res;
    String MainID;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_2 + " TEXT," + COL_3 + " TEXT,"
                + COL_4 + " TEXT," + COL_5 + " TEXT," + COL_6 + " TEXT," + COL_7 + " TEXT," + COL_8 + " TEXT," + COL_9 + " TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exist " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }



    public Integer InsertValues(String title, String Desc, String Venue, String Lat, String Long, String Addr,String Date, String Time)

    {
        myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cV = new ContentValues();
        cV.put(COL_2,title);
        cV.put(COL_3,Desc);
        cV.put(COL_4,Venue);
        cV.put(COL_5,Lat);
        cV.put(COL_6,Long);
        cV.put(COL_7,Addr);
        cV.put(COL_8,Date);
        cV.put(COL_9, Time);
        long isInserted = myDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cV);
        if ( isInserted == -1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

        /*public String getDataForBrowse()
        {
           String[] columns = new String[]{COL_1,COL_4,COL_5,COL_6,COL_7};
            Cursor c = myDB.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
            String result= " ";
            int iID = c.getColumnIndex(COL_1);
            int iVenue = c.getColumnIndex(COL_4);
            int iLat = c.getColumnIndex(COL_5);
            int iLong = c.getColumnIndex(COL_6);
            int iAddress = c.getColumnIndex(COL_7);
            for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
            {
               result = c.getString(iID) +"," + c.getString(iVenue) + "," + c.getString(iLat) + "," + c.getString(iLong) +  "," + c.getString(iAddress);
             }
            return result;
        }*/


    public Cursor getData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * From "+TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }


    public Cursor getDataById(int IDD)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        res = db.rawQuery("Select * From "+TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_1 + " = " + IDD, null);

        return res;
    }






}
```

I want the record to move to previous, whenever I click on previous Button.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in switch case where you increase IDD++.

It should increase before you call

```
 cursor = myDB.getDataById(IDD);
```

so at last your code for case R.id.bNext: should like

```
  case R.id.bNext:

            IDD = IDD + 1;
            cursor = myDB.getDataById(IDD);
            IDToPass = String.valueOf(IDD);
            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {


                VENUE = cursor.getString(3);
                DATE = cursor.getString(7);
                TIME = cursor.getString(8);
                ADDR = cursor.getString(6);
                Toast.makeText(this, IDToPass , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tVTime.setText(TIME);
                tVDate.setText(DATE);
                tVenue.setText(VENUE);
                tVAddress.setText(ADDR);
            }

            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it By removing the "IDD" Argument  From :

```
public Cursor getDataById()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        res = db.rawQuery("Select * From "+TABLE_NAME, null);

        return res;
    }
```